# Inheriting from List<T>

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, collections

What is the fastest way to implement a new class that inherits from `List<T>`?

```
class Animal {}

class Animals : List<Animal> {} // (1)
```

One problem I've encountered: By simply doing **(1)**, I've found that I'm not getting the benefit of inheriting any constructors from `List<T>`.

In the end, I'd like `Animals` to behave a lot like a `List<T>` (e.g., can be constructed, compatibility with Linq). But in addition, I'd also like to be able to add my own custom methods.

Comment: What you've posted looks pretty good to me!

Comment: Your code above would do it. You would need to implement any constructors and just call through to the relevant constructor on the base call (List<Animal>). You can create any custom methods within the Animals class

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Inheritance Problem with List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898152/c-inheritance-problem-with-listt)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want to create a **publicly exposed** animal collection you should not inherit from `List<T>` and instead inherit from [`Collection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) and use the postfix `Collection` in the class name. Example: `AnimalCollection : Collection<Animal>`.

This is supported by the [framework design guidelines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2004/09/28/design-guidelines-digest/), more specifically:

> **DO NOT** use `ArrayList`, `List<T>`,
>   `Hashtable`, or `Dictionary<K,V>` in
>   public APIs. Use `Collection<T>`,
>   `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`,
>   `KeyedCollection<K,T>`, or
>   CollectionBase subtypes instead. Note
>   that the generic collections are only
>   supported in the Framework version 2.0
>   and above.

Comment: I fail to understand why I should follow this guideline.

Comment: +1 this would really make sense if the OP wants to do something within the list itself.The OP could override basic methods. I don't really see any other value in inherit from a `List<T>` just to call your list type `Animal` right?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes, it's a *guideline* like any other, but if you provide a typed collection in your public API you can change it in future versions since it's your type. If you directly use List<T>, then you're out of luck.

Comment: also consider using interfaces i.e. ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IDictionary<TKey,TValue> etc.

Comment: @Martinho: maybe 'cause you can't override Add/Remove methods while with `Collection<T>` you can. BTW, I'd prefer to implement `IList<T>`or `ICollection<T>` using an inner `List<T>` instead of inherit from `Collection<T>`...

Comment: @digEmAll: What **you** want to override has no bearing on the public API. If I don't want to override anything, the fact that Add/Remove aren't virtual isn't a problem. What matters is what you want to make overridable by clients. @João: ok, that makes sense. I prefer using the interfaces with an inner List, as that gives you even more flexibility.

Comment: @Martinho: yes, you're right.. public API is not for implementers but for users :)

Comment: what `public APIs` actually stands for..?? is this like FB API or Google API for developers..??

Comment: I wanted access to the IEnumerable extension methods, so deriving from List<T> was the best case for me

Comment: @TomBeech, `Collection<T>` implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`. What did you get with `List<T>` that you would not get with `Collection<T>`?

Comment: @JoãoAngelo I don't know about him, but I ended up at this question because I needed `List.AddRange` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474863/addrange-to-a-collection). How come only the class that you're not supposed to inherit from has this utility method? Wouldn't it be possible to add several elements to any collection? I feel like I'm missing some nuance about which logical construct `Collection` and `List` are supposed to correspond to.

Comment: @Superbest, you should not inherit because it was not designed for extension but you can have your custom collection use composition with a inner list and then expose an `AddRange` method. As to the reasoning behind the disparity between lists and collections I can't help you there.

Comment: Why????????????

Answer (score 32):

Constructors are not inherited along with the class. You have to reimplement your desired constructors.

```
public class AnimalsCollection : List<Animal>
{
     public AnimalsCollection(IEnumerable<Animal> animals) : base(animals) {} 
}
```

Comment: Downvoters want to say why? He asked why he "didn't have any constructors", which is why my answer is the way it is. If you disagree, how about leaving some feedback?

Comment: Same reason as for Tokk. But this shows once again why anonymous downvotes suck: It’s just not helping.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: what wasn't the OP's question.

Comment: see: stackoverflow.com/questions/3748931/ stackoverflow.com/questions/898152/ stackoverflow.com/questions/794679/ stackoverflow.com/questions/5207459/ stackoverflow.com/questions/2136213/ stackoverflow.com/questions/349904 stackoverflow.com/questions/1257214

Comment: @George Stocker: That still wasn't the OP's question. It's good to give him a nudge in a better direction, but I sort of hate that we have to analyze every person's approach before answering the actual question the person had. Knowing that constructors are not inherited is a useful thing on its own.

Comment: @Anderson The correct answer is "Don't do that, do this instead." When someone is holding a gun wrongly, you don't gently tell them, "You shouldn't point that at your foot.", you take their hand and move the gun away from where ever they are pointing it.  After that's done, then you can debate the virtue of whether you should let them point a gun at their own head.

Comment: @Anderson Yes but the general sentiment here isn’t to give the OPs a fish but to teach them fishing. *That said*, I wouldn’t have downvoted this answer and I I can only say again that anonymous downvotes suck.

Comment: Honestly I'm facing this problem myself and all the arguments I see against doing it this way are YAGNI.  I really want a list class, but want to decorate it with a few extensions that don't break the encapsulation of the list.  I'm unlikely to ever want to implement or inherit any other interfaces.  I might be wrong about that in the very, very long run, but in that case I haven't painted myself into a corner doing this and I can refactor after I really hit those problems.

Answer (score 14):

Deriving from `List<T>` is not advised. Primarily because List was never meant for extension, but for performance.

If you want to create your own specific collection, you should inherit from `Collection<T>`. In your case it would be:

```
class Animals : Collection<Animal> {}
```

Comment: I did according to ur advice and inherits from `Collection<MyClass>`. But having problem somewhere like `Collection<T>` does not support methods like `Sort`, `Find`, `FindAll` and many more very useful methods. I have to change it to inherit from `List<MyClass>`. Is there any thing that I can do..?

Comment: @shashwat It doesn't have those methods because a `Collection` is supposed to be a general class for representing any group of items. For instance, a mathematical set has no specific order, and cannot be sorted. `Find` may be ambiguous if elements are not unique. Both of these cases should be part of what `Collection` can be used for, so it cannot include `Sort` and `Find` without losing generality. Although there should probably be a `ListCollection : Collection`, since it seems that that's what people use it for most commonly.

Answer (score 6):

Bear in mind that inheriting from List isn't as fully featured as you may need, a lot of the members are not virtual so the only way of covering the base implementation is to shadow it with the `new` syntax (as opposed to `override`).

If you need to start exposing custom behaviour on standard list actions, I would implement all the list interfaces on a type that simply uses an inner list for the actual storage.

This is heavily dependent on your final requirements.

Comment: I did according to ur advice and inherits from `Collection<MyClass>`. But having problem somewhere like `Collection<T>` does not support methods like `Sort`, `Find`, `FindAll` and many more very useful methods. I have to change it to inherit from `List<MyClass>`. Is there any thing that I can do..?

Comment: @shashwat `Sort`, `Find` and `FindAll` etc can be implemented in terms of LINQ for `IEnumerable<T>`, so this is not a problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Animals : List<Animal> {}
```

seemes the best way, because you can use it just after defining it like this.

So my advice is your questions title: **`Inherit List<T>`** ;-)

Comment: Didn’t donwnvote but as a general rule you should *never* inherit from the concrete collection classes (and in fact they *should* have been made `sealed`). It is much preferred to either implement an interface or inherit from an abstract base class (such as `Collection<T>`).

Comment: Agreed with Konrad. Inheriting from `List<T>` is one of those things you should not do. Been discussed hundreds of times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748931/inheriting-listt-to-implement-collections-a-bad-idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898152/c-inheritance-problem-with-listt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794679/question-inheriting-from-listof-t-class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207459/inheriting-from-listt-in-net-vb-or-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136213/c-inherit-from-dictionary-iterate-over-keyvaluepairs/2136235#2136235 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/349904/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257214/

Answer (score 4):

It isn't necessary to inherit from `List` to use collection initialization syntax or use Linq extension methods.

Just implement `IEnumerable` and also an `Add` method.