# VB Reference parent member of a class through a child when using List Of(T)

Tags: vb.net, oop, constructor, polymorphism, parent-child

If I start by pointing you to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303770/vb-polymorphism-constructors-default-and-properties-similar-class-to-listbox), which was perfectly answered for what I needed, only for one problem of trying to be able to point a transaction back to the client.

Is anyone able to help with this? Thanks again in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need bi-directional association.  This means that `Client` has a reference to `Transactions` and visa versa.

You already have the Client to Transactions covered.  There is nothing in the implementation of `List Of(T)` that will provide a reference from the child elements to the parent (Or to the parent of the List to be more accurate).

You have provide the implementation yourself.  One approach is:

```
Public Class Transaction
    Private ReadOnly _client as Client

    Sub New (client As Client)
        _client = client
    End Sub
End Class
```

Thereby enforcing the rule that each transaction should be associated to a client.

Usage would then be:

```
Dim cl as new Client()
cl.Transactions.Add(new Transaction(cl))
```