# Difference between List<String> and defined StringList

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any difference in performance between returning a `List<String>` or returning a `StringList`? where StringList would be defined as

```
class StringList : List<String> { }
```

This would also count for any other defined list such as `IntList` or `ObjectList` or `ControlList` or `MyCustomClassList`, all defined in a similar way.

The only difference i have seen is readability within the code, would any performance differences be optimised away by the compiler?

Secondly, is there a better way to define StringList or is this way the only way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376203/inherit-listt?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Did you **notice** any performance impact? I guess not. `List<string>` is clear and readable. There's no need to have a custom class for each bit of code.

Comment: Would you also work with `Int32List` or `DoubleList` or `DateTimeBooleanTupleList`? To me `List<int>` or `List<double>` or `List<Tuple<DateTime, bool>>` would be more readable.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? Why you need youre own List<String>. I would recommend you to implement IList<String> but not List<String> if you need to add few more usefull features to your inheriter

Comment: What you describe would be exactly the same object.  It only adds confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you going to extend the functionality of `List<string>`, i.e. add methods, override methods? If not, there's no point of adding this new class.

And I am not sure about the readability - if someone see `List<string>` he is sure that this is generic list of strings and he knows what to expect. But he can't be sure what `StringList` class does, he will have to dive into the source code and that means using Reflector or such tool when the source code is not available.

Comment: +1, my thoughts exactly.  `List<string>` is pretty self-explanatory and standard across all C# code that uses it.  On seeing `StringList` I would wonder what the hell it was and why it was different.

Answer (score 3):

There should be no bigger difference in performance in your case.

A better way to define `StringList` would be something like

```
using StringList = System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;
```

as it makes more clear that you do not want to make additions to that definition.
Making a `class` / using inheritance is a good way if you want to extend something.

But, I still recommend to use `List<string>`, as every single C# programmer will know what it is. Having custom defines for every possible datatype makes code unnecessary hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

It only will make a sence when you try to make a implementation of a generic List of your some custom class for adding new functionality and overriding some common features. But I would recommend to implement the `IList<>` not the `List<>`. Making new class which implements List of String doesn't makes sence.