# Making a custom class availabe to LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq

I have a basic collection class that simply wraps a list of a custom object, held in a List variable to allow me to use this[] indexing.

However, I now want to make the class accessible for be able to run **from item in collection**  LINQ queries

Using a simplified analogy, I can get a staff member from the list by just doing

```
Employeex = MyStaffList[Payroll];
```

...but what I now want to do is

```
var HREmps = from emp in StaffList
             where emp.Department == "HR"
             select emp;
```

Below is proto-type class definition....

```
public class StaffList
{
    List<Employee> lst = new List<Employee>();

    public StaffList()
    {
        /* Add Employees to the list */
    }

    public Employee this[string payroll]
    {
        get
        {
            Employee oRet = null;
            foreach (Employee emp in lst)
            {
                if (emp.Payroll.Equals(payroll, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    oRet = emp ;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return (oRet);
        }
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Payroll;
    public string Department;
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: Four upvotes in two minutes? For this to be a _good_ question, it requires to be a bit more informative: what have you tried (searching the web), what does this code do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to make your class implement `IEnumerable<Employee>` in order to enable LINQ. That's easy enough to do (there is only one method and it can just `return lst.GetEnumerator();`.

However, what is even easier is to derive from `List<Employee>` directly instead of deriving from `object`. Is there a reason you don't do that?

Comment: Yep, that's the one.... I had tried IEnumerble and IEnumerator interfaces, but not IEnumerble<T>

As for the "why not derive from List<Employee>", I never thought to do that... Two lessons learnt in one day ...

Thanks Jon

Comment: @Jon... Further to the "Derive from List<Employee>" - I was trying to get this working and then came across this

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376203/inherit-listt

... Apparently, deriving from List<T> is not advised, so have switched to Collection<T>

Comment: @ChrisHammond: Thanks, noted for future reference.