# Linq cast to list<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

```
public class Column
{
    public String Name;
    public String Value;
}

public class ColumnList : List<Column> {}
```

Then I do:

```
var cols = (from c in othercolumnlist
            select new Column
            {
               Name = c.Name,
            }).ToList() as ColumnList;
```

However it returns null. How can I successfully cast into my list?

Comment: Do you really have to inherit from `List<T>`?? you may see this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376203/inherit-listt

Comment: Why should [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the BCL return an instance of your custom class `ColumnList` (which is what you hope for by applying the `as` operator)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to do is equivalent to this:

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
Dog dog = animal as Dog;
```

One possible solution is to provide a constructor that takes an existing list, and calls the base constructor, such as:

```
public class ColumnList : List<Column>
{
    public ColumnList(IEnumerable<Column> collection):
         base(collection)
    {
    }
}
```

And then build your `ColumnList` from an existing collection.

```
var collection = othercolumnlist.Select(c => new Column { Name = c.Name });

var columnList = new ColumnList(collection);
```

---

You could also provide an extension method to make this easier:

```
public static class ColumnListExtensions
{
    public static ToColumnList(this IEnumerable<Column> collection)
    {
        return new ColumnList(collection);
    }   
}

var cols = othercolumnlist.Select(c => new Column { Name = c.Name })
           .ToColumnList();
```

Answer (score 7):

`ColumnList` is a `List<Column>` but `List<Column>` is not a `ColumnList`. Consider `Animal` and `Dog` classes:

```
public class Animal
{
}

public class Dog: Animal
{
}
```

What you are trying to do is treat any animal as dog. But not all animals are dogs. There can be `Cat` or `Kangaroo`. Thats why `as ColumnList` returns `null`.

You need to create new `ColumnList` instance instead and add columns to it manually:

```
var columnList = new ColumnList();
columnList.AddRange(othercolumnlist.Select(c => new Column { Name = c.Name }));
```

---

If you need to do this often, then you can add static creation method to your `ColumnList` class:

```
public static ColumnList CreateFrom(ColumnList other)
{
     var columnList = new ColumnList();
     columnList.AddRange(other.Select(c => new Column { Name = c.Name }));
     return columnList;
}
```

And use it this way:

```
var columnList = ColumnList.CreateFrom(otherColumnList);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is down-cast `List<Column>` to `ColumnList` which assumes that all `List<T>`'s are `ColumnList`'s - which obviously they aren't.

What you can do however is initialize a new instance of `ColumnList` by passing the result of your query

```
new ColumnList().AddRange(othercolumnlist
    .Select(x => new Column { Name = x.Name })
    .ToList());
```

Comment: Um, you can't upcast? Sure you can. `(object)"Hello world"`

Comment: @LewsTherin `string` derives from `object` therefore your example is not upcasting, it's downcasting (which is perfectly legal). Upcasting would be going `var obj = new object(); string str = (string)obj` - and although that will work, `string` is a special type of object and is treated differently by the CLR.

Comment: string derives from object and I am casting from string to object. It is up casting. I am casting up the inheritance chain.

Comment: @LewsTherin ah wait - I have completely confused the definitions there, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You could if you define a copy constructor for your `ColumnList` type:

```
public class ColumnList : List<Column>
{
    public ColumnList(IEnumerable<Column> src) : base(src)
    {
    }
}
```

And you then do:

```
var cols = new ColumnList(from c in othercolumnlist
            select new Column
            {
               Name = c.Name,
            }).ToList());
```

Reason being `ToList()` returns a `List` and not a `ColumnList`. It can only ever be a `ColumnList` if you explicitly instantiate it as one, but never vice-versa.