# Correct use of C# 'new' modifier to make protected property public

Tags: c#, inheritance

Let's say I have an **abstract base class**:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    private MyObject myObject;

    protected MyObject PropA
    {
        get
        {
            if(myObject == null) this.myObject = new MyObject();
            return this.myObject;
        }
    }
}
```

...and that in one of my **derived** classes, I want to make the **protected** base class property `PropA` **public**. Would it be correct to use the [`new` modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) in this context?

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new MyObject PropA
    {
        get
        {
            return base.PropA;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not terribly wrong.  Why you couldn't just make it public in the base class is hard to guess.  A client programmer with just a BaseClass reference is going to cast himself into trouble, perhaps.

Comment: Well, its technically correct but, at first glance, it seems like a dubious design. Why is `PropA` protected if it can be made public in certain derived classes? Why not make it public to begin with? What makes a public `PropA` a bad design in other derived classes?

Answer (score 4):

> Would it be correct use of the new modifier in this context?

Technically - yes, there will no errors or warnings.

As for me, using of new keyword itself as a modifier indicates a design drawback.

I'll give one example.

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int AddCallsCount;
    public new void Add(T t)
    {
        AddCallsCount++;
        base.Add(t);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class Test
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestThatsNotGood()
    {
        List<object> list = new MyList<object>();
        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(2);

        MyList<object> myList = list as MyList<object>;

        Assert.AreEqual(0, myList.AddCallsCount);

    }
}
```

It looks like polymorphism works, but actually does not.

UPDATE:
Ok, there is very simplified explanation. I omit explanation of what polymorphism is.

Polymorphims is realized with implementation of `abstract\virtual` and `overriding` methods. As soon as neither `virtual` nor `override` modifiers are specified `MyList<T>.Add` is just another 'common' public method. And with `MyList<T>` inherited `List<T>`, `MyList<T>.Add` 'hides' `List<T>.Add` because name and parameters of both methods are same.

At lower level: as soon as `List<T>` type definition of method `Add` isn't marked with `virtual` keyword, compiler won't search for overriding methods of actual instance type (`MyList<T>` in this certain case) for variable of given type (`List<T>` in this certain case).

Definetely it may lead to logic errors and incorrect usage of class API.

Hence, compiler 'thinks' that probably there is a logical mistake or design drawback and warns programmer. The `new` keyword is just a way to talk to the compiler

> yes, I know that it's not good, but I need it because of my bad design

.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain why (and where) polymorphism is (surprisingly) failing. Also, inheriting from `List<T>` is arguably [*not* a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5376343/1497596).

Comment: @DavidRR, you may change List<T> to SomeBaseClass and MyList<T> to SomeDerivedClass. It doesn't matter. List example is natural and it's first one that I've bethought.

Answer (score 4):

The `new` keyword works and is correct, if you want to add a member in a derived class that has the same name as a member in the base class; however, it seems that this design defies the purpose of abstract classes. Make `PropA` public and virtual in the base class or public and abstract:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    // Property not implemented here.
    public abstract MyObject PropA { get; }

    private MyObject _propB;
    // Property implemented, but implementation can be overridden in derived class.
    public virtual MyObject PropB
    {
        get { return _propB ?? (_propB = new MyObject()); }
    }

    public int PropC { get { return 5; } }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // You must provide an implementation here.
    private MyObject _propA;
    public override MyObject PropA
    {
        get { return _propA ?? (_propA = new MyObject()); }
    }

    // You are free to override this property and to provide an new implementation
    // or to do nothing here and to keep the original implementation.
    public override MyObject PropB
    {
        get { return <new implementation...>; }
    }

    // PropC is inherited as is and is publicly visible through DerivedClass as well. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Anytime you have a class with a member that has the same name as a member in an inherited class you need to use the new keyword (even if the two properties/methods have different return types).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you perhaps

```
public new string test { 
                          get { return (this as T).test; } 
                          set { (this as T).test = value; } 
                       }
```

because `base` give you only parent but if you want to go higher you have to cast.