# C# Class Add ID from one class to another

Tags: c#

i have one class named with Animal, with Name, Type, Gender, and i have another class named with AnimalList, i need to know how can i add Animals to my AnimalList, this is my class animal(im in console application):
Filename Animal.cs

```
class Animal
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public string Type {get; set;}
  public string Gender {get; set;}

  public Person(string name, string type, string gender)
  {
       Name = name;
       Type = type;
       Gender = gender;
  }
}
```

And my class AnimalList:
FilenameAnimalList.cs

```
class AnimalList: List<Animal>
{
     what should i do to add Animals to this list
}
```

shouldn't be better  like this?

```
public new void Add(Animal value)
{
}
```

Comment: You need an instance of the list to add animals to it, at the moment you have two class definitions, these just describe the classes but don't utilise them in any way. Do you have a program (forms, wpf, console app etc)?

Comment: `List<T>` Already has the `.Add(T item)` therefor it would be pointless to create a method Add because you will have to specify the `new` BUT by doing that you will not have access to the internal structure of Add(T item).
That would cause that you will not be able to store the `Animal value` in the internal structure of `List<T>`

Comment: Working fiddle of how the code should be:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/dkIEM5

Comment: Also read the following, on StackOverFlow  it is suggested not to inherit from List<T> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376203/inheriting-from-listt/5376343#5376343

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiate your `AnimalList` class somewhere(for example in main method) and then add the instances of an `Animal` class.

for example:

```
var animals = new AnimalList();

animals.Add(new Animal() {
   Name = "", 
   Type = "", 
   Gender = ""});
```

Comment: Check `animalList` and `animals` fyi :)

Comment: You should rename `animalList` to `animals` or vice versa . Also your code is not a valid C# code.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you have the constructor for `Person` in your `Animal` class?

Do like this:

```
var animals = new AnimalList();
var animal = new Animal();
animals.Add(animal);
```

You have to make your Animal class public:

```
public class Animal
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make your class Public
And do this:

```
 AnimalList animalList = new AnimalList();
            Animal animal = new Animal();
            animal.Name = "x";
            animal.Type = "Y";
            animal.Gender = "M/F";
            animalList.add(animal);
```