# C# Save from list

Tags: c#, list, class

Hello i have one class called Animal.cs and in my Program.cs i have created some animals..

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var AnimalList = new AnimslList();
        animalList.Add(new Animal{ Active = true, Name = "Bob", Photo = "Espanha" });
        animalList.Add(new Animal { Active = false, Name = "Robby", Photo = "Portugal" });
        animalList.Add(new Animal { Active = true, Name = "Snoop", Photo = "UK" });
        }
     }
```

and i have one class AnimalList.cs and in that class i added Animal list, and im getting the active animals with this code:

```
class AnimalList : List<Animal>
{
    public List<Animal> GetActiveAnimals()
    {
        return this.FindAll(p => p.Active);
    }
}
```

and my problem is in this class he called Event.cs in event.cs i want get the results from GetActiveAnimals() because i just want to get the active animals for the event can someone help me please?

```
class Event
    {
        private AnimalList _contestants;
    }
```

i should get the Active from the AnimaList in this one above.
The active ones should go into _contestants

Comment: Are you and [@Tiago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36712816/3970411) working on same project?

Comment: You'll need to provide us with more relevant code and the actual problem you're facing here - *what* event, for starters?

Comment: @dotctor no but i will give him help i have the solution for him

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend your Event by a constructor for example

```
class Event
{
    private AnimalList _contestants;
    public Event(AnimalList contestants)
    { 
         _contestants = contestants;
    }
}
```

and then forward the list when you create an event:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var AnimalList = new AnimslList();
    animalList.Add(new Animal{ Active = true, Name = "Bob", Photo = "Espanha" });
    animalList.Add(new Animal { Active = false, Name = "Robby", Photo = "Portugal" });
    animalList.Add(new Animal { Active = true, Name = "Snoop", Photo = "UK" });
    var event = new Event(AnimalList.GetActiveAnimals();
}
```