# Binding Nested List to DropdownListFor with List<SelectListItem>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, foreach, nested-lists, selectlistitem

I want to pass a nested list (`List<OptionValueList>`) to a View; then render each corresponding `List<OptionValue>` inside @Html.DropdownListFor.

Class:

```
public class OptionValue
{
   public int OptionID { get; set; }
   public int ValueID { get; set; }
   public string ValueName { get; set; }      
}
public class OptionValueListList : List<OptionValueList> { }
public class OptionValueList : List<OptionValue> { }
```

I fill the class `OptionValueListList` from db, but I couldn't adapt it in `SelectListItem` in order to bind data to @HtmlDropdownListFor.

Below is my View:

```
    @model Program.Models.OptionValueListList

    @foreach (var item in Model) /*List<OptionValueList>*/
    {
         foreach (var y in item) /*List<OptionValue>*/
         {        
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>y.ValueID, new SelectList(@ViewBag.x, "Value", "Text"), "Option Values")
       }
     }
```

And below is where I try to pass data and could not bind properly as it renders same dropdownlistfor for 18 times:

```
   OptionValueListList o = new OptionValueListList();
   o = pr.GetOptionsForProduct(id);
   foreach (var item in o)
   {
        foreach (var i in item)
        {
             List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
             li = (from c in item
                  select new SelectListItem
                  {
                        Text = c.ValueName,
                        Value = c.ValueID.ToString()
                  }).ToList();
              ViewBag.x = li;
         }  
    }
```

The problem in `ViewBag.x = li;` Where should I put this Viewbag? Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message are you receiving? Moreover its still not clear what are you expecting.

Comment: I need to pass `OptionValueListList` type to `List<SelectListItem>` list to bind dropdowns in the view. As there will be multiple dropdowns, I have a nested list of type `OptionValueListList`. I used to pass a simple list with `List<SelectListItem>` but I could not do it for 2 dimensional one. I don't get errors except it doesnt recognize my classes.. @TanvirArjel

Comment: Add the exact error message to the question please!

Comment: @TanvirArjel I just added the error message

Comment: Wait! I shall back to your soon.

Comment: Regarding your class structure which inherits from `List<T>`, you should consider reading [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376203/inheriting-from-listt). Instead of inheriting from `List<T>`, use `Collection<T>` instead.

Comment: I tried using Collection<T> instead, but it still does not pass the nested lists to `SelectListItem` neighter. @TetsuyaYamamoto